# Posterize Node in Material Shader?

Tags: materials, shaders, shader-nodes

I have an image on a plane, is it possible to limit the number of colors on that image, sort of like the posterize node in the compositor but within the material shader?

[image: Compositor Posterize Node]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**//EDIT:** Okay, I actually didn't think of a much easier solution. The answer below is completely valid and working, but for the vector maths there is a shortcut: instead of upscaling the colors by the step size, then flooring them and downscaling by the step size reciprocal, you can simply use the step size reciprocal in a *Vector Math* node set to *Snap* (for the long explanation read the answer below):

[image: posterize with snap]

Yes, it is actually not too complicated if you know what's going on in the *Posterize* node.

When you set the steps to something like 8, it means the complete range from 0 to 1 (or 0 to 255 in RGB values) will be reduced to only 8 colors per channel or 512 in total, because it's the number of steps to the power of 3, in this example $$8^3=512.$$

With the colors in the 0 to 1 range you can simply calculate this conversion by the following formula:

$$\frac{\lfloor color\cdot steps\rfloor}{steps}$$

So you multiply the image colors by the number of steps you want to have, e.g. 8. Then your colors range from 0 to 8 instead of 0 to 1. Then you use the floor function to cut off the decimal part, i.e. 0.245 becomes 0, 3.712 becomes 3 and so on. Afterwards you divide it by the steps to convert it back to the 0 to 1 range.

Doing this in the shader nodetree looks like this: you take a *Value* where you can set the steps, a *Vector Math* node set to *Scale* to uniformly multiply all colors with this value. Then comes a *Vector Math* node set to *Floor* to cut off the decimals, then another *Scale* node, this time you first divide 1 by the steps value to get the reciprocal and plug this into the *Scale* node.

[image: posterize vector math]

You could now even select the *Vector Math* nodes and the *Math* > *Divide* node and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to make this a node group and rename the inputs etc. so that you have your own *Posterize* node in the *Shader Editor*.

[image: posterize nodegroup]

Comment: Ah yes that's so simple. works perfectly. Thank you

Comment: @SarahLee It could be even simpler, see my edit at the top of the answer. I was thinking overly complicated and didn't think of all the functions that are available in the _Vector Math_ node.